# No OpenID endpoint found while connecting to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller, openid

I have the following code in the AuthConfig.cs(MVC Application) file ,

```
public static void RegisterAuth()
        {       

            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();

            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new WordpressOpenId(), "wordpress", null);

        }
public class WordpressOpenId : OpenIdClient
    {
        public WordpressOpenId()
            : base("wordpress", "https://example.wordpress.com")
        {
        }
    }
```

While trying to login to WordPress it shows "No OpenID endpoint found" error.
I could connect to google and yahoo using openid but i have problem with Wordpress alone.
Could you please tell what need to be done?